# How to get name of "named row" in Dataset for function applied to each row

Tags: function-construction, dataset

After some calculations and a `GroupBy` I have a `Dataset` that is structured like this.

```
dat = Dataset@<|
   "Apples" -> 
    ConstantArray[Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> {300, Automatic}], 3],
   "Oranges" -> 
    ConstantArray[Graphics[{Orange, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> {300, Automatic}], 
     2],
   "Bananas" -> 
    ConstantArray[Graphics[{Yellow, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> {300, Automatic}], 5]
   |>
```

I now would like to apply a function to each of these rows that uses the row name in first row for for a `Grid`.  However, I have been unable to figure out how to reference the row name using the *dataset[All, f]* query syntax as provided in the [Dataset | Dataset Queries documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html).

I can do the `Grid` without the row name with:

```
dat[All, Grid[Partition[#, 2, 2, {1, 1}, ""]] &]
```

How do I reference the row name in the function? Is there some syntax of `Keys` that I should be using?  I think not as `Keys` would give me the keys of the row columns. I'm looking for some sort of `ParentKey` function such that I could get the row's key for the grid. e.g.

```
dat[All,
 Grid[
   Join[ 
    {{ParentKey@#, SpanFromLeft}},
    Partition[#, 2, 2, {1, 1}, ""]
    ]] &]
```

Comment: On my 10.3 Mathematica automatically adds a column with the row names when executing your `Grid` code (because `Dataset`), just FYI.

Comment: @Graumagier  Yes, that is correct; I too am on 10.3.  What I would like to do is reference that "row" column in the function that is being mapped across the rows. It is a row indicator column.

Comment: `dat[KeyTake["Apples"], All]`?

Comment: @J. M. Maybe something along the lines of `dat[Grid@Transpose@{Keys@#, Values@#} &]`?

Comment: @Grau, except that I have a feeling that this is doable without transposing...

Comment: I have a feeling that it would be much easier to simply pull the data from the dataset and do the formatting "externally", but that might simply be my limited experience with dataset-related stuff…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [Associations guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Associations.html) in the documentation I came across [`KeyValueMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyValueMap.html) that can be applied to the entire table.  Since the `Dataset` has named rows then the key will be the row name and the value will be the row.

```
dat[
  KeyValueMap[
   Function[{key, value},
    Grid[Join[{{key, SpanFromLeft}}, Partition[value, 2, 2, {1, 1}, ""]]]
    ]]
  ] // Normal
```

Now I can convert the notebook into a template notebook for reporting. :-)

Comment: Can also use `Underscript` in lieu of the 2nd part: `dat[All, Grid[Partition[#, 2, 2, {1, 1}, ""]] &][ 
 KeyValueMap[Underscript]]`